# VS2013 Update 2/3 typescript crash when debugging MVC app - any suggestions?

Tags: typescript

VS2013 Update 2/3 typescript crash when debugging MVC app - any suggestions?

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
Stack:
at    TypeScriptDebugEngine.DebugMonitor.ScriptDocumentNotifications.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.ComponentInterfaces.IDkmScriptDocumentTreeNodeUnloadNotification.OnScriptDocumentTreeNodeUnload(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Script.DkmScriptDocumentTreeNode, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.DkmEventDescriptor)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.EntryPoint.IDkmScriptDocumentTreeNodeUnloadNotification_OnScriptDocumentTreeNodeUnload(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this has been addressed for VS2013 Update 3 RTW

https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2568

Comment: Anyone have a release window for the RTW? Crashing every hour right now!

Answer (score 0):

You could run devenv /log and then look in %appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml to see if there are more detailed explanations.  The file is usually large so if you don't know but can find the relevant block, you can post it up and we can try to assist.

Comment: nothing in that file except a bunch of <entry> items.  No error messages.

Comment: OK, that isn't right.  Mine is full of entries even when I have no issue.  Just to clarify, command line with admin permissions, browse to IDE folder of Visual Studio version you are using.  type devenv /log.  It will then create that file in the above path, recreate your error and then go take a look.

Comment: how do I post a file here?  File contents are too large to post as text.

Comment: Was only suggesting a small segment of it, but you can upload to Onedrive etc.  Take a look at the other answer as that be the resolution.